# How to detect if connection is unsuccessful using Watin?

Tags: c#, watin

I have a project about going to a website. If the website cannot because of  several reasons, such as not being connected to the Internet, wrong proxy ip, etc,  the browser will show a page with text "You're not connected to a network". In this situation, I want to auto refresh the  browser. How will the program detect that website can't be loaded? 
Take a look at my below code:

```
   public void exam()
        {
            var ie = new IE();
            ie.GoTo("http://search.yahoo.com");
            ie.WaitForComplete(5);            
            if (ie.ContainsText("You're not connected to a network"))
            {
                ie.Close();// or ie.Refresh()
            }

        }
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to use C# .Net functions in Watin?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing to see if you can Ping the address first ... try using this

```
   public bool CanConnect()
   {
    var ping = new Ping();
    var reply = ping.Send("search.yahoo.com");
    return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
   }
```

or if you want to pass the address as a parameter:

```
   public bool CanConnect(string addressToTest)
   {
    var ping = new Ping();
    var reply = ping.Send(addressToTest);
    return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I has a error: "An exception occurred during a Ping request".

Comment: oh, thank you , just use: search.yahoo.com , not "http://". It worked, thank again !

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553320/c-sharp-how-to-detect-if-website-return-page-with-content-this-page-cannot-be]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553320/c-sharp-how-to-detect-if-website-return-page-with-content-this-page-cannot-be  It seems this solution doest work with "This page cannot be displayed". Can you give me a advise!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean