# C# - How to detect if website return page with content "This page cannot be displayed "using Watin?

Tags: c#, watin

I have a project about going to a website. If the website cannot be loaded, and the browser will show a page with text: "This page cannot be displayed" .In this situation, I want to auto refresh the browser. How will the program detect that website can't be loaded? . I've tried Ping() to check the connection, but it seems the connection is fine. Take a look at my below code:

```
public void exam()
        {
            var ie = new IE();
            ie.GoTo("http://search.yahoo.com");
            ie.WaitForComplete(5);            
            if (ie.ContainsText("This page cannot be displayed"))
            {
                ie.Close();// or ie.Refresh()
            }

        }
```

It doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `IE` type is but you could use `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse` and check the `StatusCode` property of the response.

For example: -

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    //page not found
}
//etc....
```

The [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) enum can be useful for checking against a variety of different states.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine just remove the time from your wait for complete
Make sure the text is same as displayed in the browser.

```
public void exam()
    {
        var ie = new IE();
        ie.GoTo("http://search.yahoo.com");
        ie.WaitForComplete();            
        if (ie.ContainsText("This page cannot be displayed"))
        {
            ie.Refresh();
        }

    }
```